# Lost permissions to tables after turning on SQL authorization in Apache Derby

Tags: derby, javadb

The database created in Java DB (Derby) was set-up as follows to allow authentication and authorization:

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.connection.requireAuthentication','true');

CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.user.normal', 'normal');

CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.fullAccessUsers', 'sa');
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers', 'normal');
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.defaultConnectionMode', 'readOnlyAccess');
```

The "sa" username was created during database creation so it is the owner of the database.

And this works as intended. I can log in as "sa" user and have full access. Or log in as "normal" users and be restricted to read only access.

Now, I want to use SQL authorization to grant specific permissions to specific users.
To do this I have to switch on SQL authorization first by executing following command:

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.sqlAuthorization', 'true');
```

Problem is, that after login in again under "sa" the system reports that I have no rights for SELECT and other statements. Moreover I loose complete ownership on the database.

Why Derby suddenly denies access to any user including the owner after executing the statement that switches on the SQL authorization?

P.S. I use Apache Derby Network Server - 10.9.1.0 which was a part of Java EE 7 installation for NetBeans 7.3

P.S 2. When after SQL authorization is set to true I try to use GRANT statement I receive following SQL error code:

```
SQL state 42506: User 'SA' is not the owner of Table/View 'SA'.'DOCTYPES'.
```

Even though the whole database was created using this username.

Comment: Have you issued any GRANT statements? http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/cdevcsecuregrantrevokeaccess.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton I can't use GRANT statement until I switch on the SQL authorization. When I do I am told I can't use GRANT statements because I don't have permissions for that.

Comment: If you bring up "ij" and log in as SA, are you able to run 'show tables' and 'describe' commands? Those may show you who is actually owning the tables in question.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I have done like you said. I can login as SA and run both commands however they don't show who is the owner of the table. When I run 'show tables' I see all the schemas. One of them is mine SA. When I run 'describe sa.doctypes' I see the table definition. When I try to use SELECT on that table I get the error about not having permission to do this. I just don't understand why after creating the database with the SA username I loose all permissions once I switch on SQL authorization.

Comment: I don't, either. You might try contacting the derby-users mailing list at Apache; there are a lot of Derby users there.